# Select dates in index

Tags: python, datetime

[image]

i have start date and end date and dataframe with daily observations. The problem is that i can't find a way, which will enable me select dates with periodicity of 3 months

for example:

2003-01-03 + 3 months = 2003-04-03 and so on

output should consist of 20 rows because 5 years with 3 months periodicity, including start and end dates

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Old solution didn't work for all cases. Therefore a new one:

```
start, end = returns.index[0], returns.index[-1]
length = (end.year - start.year) * 12 + (end.month - start.month)
if length % 3 == 0 and end.day >= start.day:
    length += 3
new_index = []
for m in range(3, length, 3):
    ydelta, month = divmod(start.month + m, 12)
    day = pd.Timestamp(year=start.year + ydelta, month=month, day=1)
    day += pd.Timedelta(f'{min(start.day, day.days_in_month) - 1}d')
    new_index.append(day)
new_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(new_index)
returns = returns.loc[new_index]
```

Another version which has some slight inaccuracies around the month ends but is more compact:

```
add_3_months = pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=3)
new_index = pd.date_range(returns.index[0] + add_3_months,
                          returns.index[-1],
                          freq=add_3_months)
returns = returns.loc[new_index]
```